# Autocomplete form from pasted JSON dump dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

I am trying to create a piece of code that will read a piece of JSON and autopopulate separate fields on the same page from the content. I would like to be able to copy/paste a chunk of JSON into a form textarea, and have separate text fields populated from the pasted JSON.

```
<form>
<textarea name="jsondump">Paste JSON here...</textarea>
<button type="button" name="populate">Populate</button> 
<input type="text" name="field1" value=""></input>
<input type="text" name="field2" value=""></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

So if I pasted a piece of JSON such as:

```
{"field1": "Apple", "field2": "Orange"}
```

into the textarea, clicking the populate button would parse the JSON and update the text inputs.

(I know it would be a lot easier to send the JSON straight from one application to the other, however they are sat on two different servers with no interaction).

I think this should be possible with javascript, any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did a lot of searching around first, all of the results i could find related to populating a form from a JSON string passed as a parameter via ajax/POST etc between pages/db, and nothing that could quickly extract variables on the same page.

Comment: Just change the post to a return of the JSON. The documentation uses a simple array: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default for the default action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a templating language such as handlebars or underscore to populate the markup from the data.

Here is a quick example of how to do that simply with underscore and jquery.

[JSbin demo](http://jsbin.com/tiniyulavo/edit?html,js,output)

JS:

```
var template = _.template(
  $( "script.template" ).html()
);

$('.form__btn').on('click', function(e){
    var data = $('.form__json').val();
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    catch (e){
        console.log(data + " is not valid JSON");
        return;
    }
    $('.form__inner').html(template(data));
});
```

Html

```
  <div class="form">
    <textarea name="jsondump" class="form__json">Paste JSON here...</textarea>
    <button type="button" name="populate" class="form__btn">Populate</button> 
    <div class="form__inner"></div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/template" class="template">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="field1" value="<%= field1 %>"></input>
      <input type="text" name="field2" value="<%= field2 %>"></input>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
  </script>
```

Note this works with your exampled pasted in

```
{"field1": "Apple", "field2": "Orange"}
```